# Is there a better way to get list of objects in JavaFX than iteration?

Tags: javafx

I have several fields with people names and their ages. Amount of those fields are random, depending on how many people are participating. I want to select in separate list all fields with names and in another all fields with ages. What way better to select all `TextFields` on page and separate them by name/age?

Comment: If you have many `TextField`s that means you have something that holds them, a `TableView`, `Hbox`, `VBox` or something right?

Comment: Yes, I have as a main parent `VBox`, which holds `StackPane`(with `Button` and another `VBox`, which has name/text for 1 person). As more people join, in `VBox` `StackPanes` are being generated for each new person.

Comment: If you want to get a list of those objects I think you can add a `List<>` then every time when you get a new object you can simply add it to that list. If you want to use them in "javafx" context, maybe its better to kepp them in an `ObservableList<>` since many javafx components has ObservableList as holding data.

Comment: Ir if you want to get a specified item without iterating you can use a `Map<K,V>` to store them, then without iteration you can simply use `map.get()`.